# SMTP RCPT TO: <wrong_username@existhost> returned 250 Accepted?

Tags: php, email, smtp

Im working with validating emails, and im using phpmailer to connect to SMTP server, send a Mail from: header and then a RCPT TO: header, but all emails i put in there, i get a 250 accepted! instead of a "No such user here".

this is part of the extended PHPMailer class that i wrote:

```
    $ret[] = $this->smtpConnect();
    $ret[] = $this->smtp->mail('valid_from@valid_from.com');
    $ret[] = $this->smtp->recipient('wrong_email@right_domain.com');
    $this->smtpClose();
```

Testing this on my own websites so I know that I do NOT have a catch all email address,

and using a validating service online seems to work perfectly testing with the same values.

Please advise.

Comment: ***Testing this on my own websites so I know that I do NOT have a catch all email address*** -  Your mail server is misconfigured

Comment: thanks for the response, :) but the other validating service(s) seem to get it right? im checking domain1 from domain2 , both on the same server,

Comment: Try to connect from a different server, the mail server may see the connection as local and accept it.

Comment: thanks for the response, Now im using a different server, and yes everything seems to work ok, except Gmail. 

I get a Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) for gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com on port 465 

my host ran a successful traceroute for this server on port 25 from my server and they say no port is blocked.

Comment: ALSO I can connect to smtp.google.com 465 but this again gives me RCPT TO: <wrong.email@gmail.com> => 250 OK;